# OpenSSL 1.0.2t build failed on MacMini M1 with MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3

Tags: openssl, clang, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I'm trying to build OpenSSL 1.0.2t from scratch (this version is required for my project but it does not supported by MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3 on Apple M1 CPU)
My build fails with `unknonw directive` message.
Could anyone explain how can I fix it?

P.S. At the moment I can't upgrade to supported OpenSSL 1.1.1

Here is the build log:

```
make all
making all in crypto...
cc -I. -I.. -I../include  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch arm64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -v -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -c -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include  -c -o arm64cpuid.o arm64cpuid.S
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: aarch64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple arm64-apple-macosx11.0.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -E -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name arm64cpuid.S -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mframe-pointer=non-leaf -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=11.1 -target-cpu vortex -target-feature +v8.3a -target-feature +fp-armv8 -target-feature +neon -target-feature +crc -target-feature +crypto -target-feature +fullfp16 -target-feature +ras -target-feature +lse -target-feature +rdm -target-feature +rcpc -target-feature +zcm -target-feature +zcz -target-feature +sha2 -target-feature +aes -target-abi darwinpcs -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 609.8 -v -resource-dir /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I . -I .. -I ../include -D OPENSSL_THREADS -D _REENTRANT -D DSO_DLFCN -D HAVE_DLFCN_H -D L_ENDIAN -D SHA1_ASM -D SHA256_ASM -D SHA512_ASM -I /opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -I/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include -O3 -Wall -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/mobiled2/Projects/OpenSSL/source/crypto -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 318 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fobjc-runtime=macosx-11.0.0 -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -o /var/folders/yh/d68xsh4x28z1t545mknzlsy00000gn/T/arm64cpuid-f4b3a2.s -x assembler-with-cpp arm64cpuid.S
clang -cc1 version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29) default target arm64-apple-darwin20.3.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 .
 ..
 ../include
 /opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang" -cc1as -triple arm64-apple-macosx11.0.0 -filetype obj -main-file-name arm64cpuid.S -target-cpu vortex -target-feature +v8.3a -target-feature +fp-armv8 -target-feature +neon -target-feature +crc -target-feature +crypto -target-feature +fullfp16 -target-feature +ras -target-feature +lse -target-feature +rdm -target-feature +rcpc -target-feature +zcm -target-feature +zcz -target-feature +sha2 -target-feature +aes -I . -I .. -I ../include -I /opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/mobiled2/Projects/OpenSSL/source/crypto -dwarf-debug-producer "Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)" -I . -I .. -I ../include -I /opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -dwarf-version=4 -mrelocation-model pic -o arm64cpuid.o /var/folders/yh/d68xsh4x28z1t545mknzlsy00000gn/T/arm64cpuid-f4b3a2.s
arm64cpuid.S:8:1: error: unknown directive
.type _armv7_neon_probe,%function
^
arm64cpuid.S:12:1: error: unknown directive
.size _armv7_neon_probe,.-_armv7_neon_probe
^
arm64cpuid.S:15:1: error: unknown directive
.type _armv7_tick,%function
^
arm64cpuid.S:19:1: error: unknown directive
.size _armv7_tick,.-_armv7_tick
^
arm64cpuid.S:22:1: error: unknown directive
.type _armv8_aes_probe,%function
^
arm64cpuid.S:26:1: error: unknown directive
.size _armv8_aes_probe,.-_armv8_aes_probe
^
arm64cpuid.S:29:1: error: unknown directive
.type _armv8_sha1_probe,%function
^
arm64cpuid.S:33:1: error: unknown directive
.size _armv8_sha1_probe,.-_armv8_sha1_probe
^
arm64cpuid.S:36:1: error: unknown directive
.type _armv8_sha256_probe,%function
^
arm64cpuid.S:40:1: error: unknown directive
.size _armv8_sha256_probe,.-_armv8_sha256_probe
^
arm64cpuid.S:42:1: error: unknown directive
.type _armv8_pmull_probe,%function
^
arm64cpuid.S:46:1: error: unknown directive
.size _armv8_pmull_probe,.-_armv8_pmull_probe
^
make[1]: *** [arm64cpuid.o] Error 1
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
mobiled2@mac-mini source %
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling assembler. I was able to compile for M1 just by using directive "no-asm" for the build script.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.