# brew install qt-webkit@2.3 failed in mac m1 chip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, qt, homebrew, capybara-webkit

Most of the commands in Apple silicon macbook is failing with below error.

I need to install `capybara-webkit`

```sh
brew tap cartr/qt4
brew install qt@4
brew install qt-webkit@2.3
gem install capybara-webkit
```

Its failing in any case i mean while installing in `qt-webkit@2.3` or
`capybara-webkit`

```
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/name/Library/Logs/Homebrew/openssl@1.0/03.make:
 ^
x86_64cpuid.s:273:10: error: unknown token in expression
 cmpq $0,%rax
         ^
x86_64cpuid.s:273:10: error: invalid operand
 cmpq $0,%rax
         ^
x86_64cpuid.s:274:9: error: unknown token in expression
 cmoveq %rcx,%rax
        ^
x86_64cpuid.s:274:9: error: invalid operand
 cmoveq %rcx,%rax
        ^
make[1]: *** [x86_64cpuid.o] Error 1
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!
```

[image: output picture]

Comment: Contact the tap maintainer. Don't waste time here. https://github.com/cartr/homebrew-qt4/issues

Comment: See the comment about using no-asm in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67238073/openssl-1-0-2t-build-failed-on-macmini-m1-with-macos-big-sur-11-2-3